# GPIO 1 not waking up the board when shorted to ground

Tags: pi-3, gpio, raspbian-stretch, shutdown, reboot

I'm trying to use a single button to put the pi in a halt state and then wake it up. I cannot use GPIO3 since I'm using i2c devices as well.

However according to this original post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24682, both GPIO1(pin28) and GPIO3 should wake the Pi up when shorted to ground.

> I've now added a way to wake the board through GPIO.
>   A falling edge on GPIO1 or GPIO3 will wake the board up, and it will continue to boot into linux.

This does not seem to be the case. While GPIO3 works perfectly, shorting GPIO1 to ground has no effect in waking the Pi back up.

What am I missing? Since I really can't use GPIO3 due to the i2c conflicts, using GPIO 1 would be ideal.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 running the latest Stretch (June 18)

Comment: you're reading a thread from 2012 - is it still relevant? was it EVER relevant to a Pi3 which was released 4 years after that discussion?

Comment: @JaromandaX the thread continues up until late 2017. I posed the same question there as well and will report back once(and if) I receive a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPIO pin is 1 for very early Pi's (model b up to rev1.1) with 26-pin header. It is 3 for all later models.

It deliberately uses an I2C pin as it needs the pull up resistor or else it may falsely trigger with nothing detected.

You can use the RUN header to boot when the pi is halted.